# how to link bootstrap and external css into laravel 5.3?

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5.3

[image]

i try to add bootstrap and external css file into my laravel project using two methods

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/scrolling-nav.css">

                                 and
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/scrolling-nav.css') }}" />
```

both way but it shows error on console. my directory structure is as shown in image please help me get out from this problem.

Comment: place your files in public folder then try..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always place your js/css files in public folder.In your case try like this.Make whole copy of assets folder inside public folder..

For Stylesheet..

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}"/>
```

And For JS file..

```
<script src="{{url('assets/js/components/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: that was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Usually you're keeping app assets in `resources/assets` directory and using [Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir) to concatinate, minify and copy assets to a `public` directory.

If you're not familiar with Elixir and Gulp, you can just put your assets to a `public` directory and load them with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/scrolling-nav.css' }}">
```